# Difference between MIPS and ARM datapaths

Tags: arm, assembly, computer-architecture, mips

I have just learnt **simplified five stage pipelined MIPS** architecture in the class. I am reading other Instruction Set Architectures (**ARM** currently) and found some differences between ARM and MIPS. Both have different instruction formats, register set, etc.

Is there any difference in the **data path** of ARM from MIPS, considering only basic instructions such as ADD, LDR, SDR, and branch instructions? because the data path involves fetching, decoding, and executing the instruction and it must be same for all Instruction Set Architectures.

I could not find the information about ARM data path from where I am reading this.

Comment: please dont cross post questions...pick one place...and we will move it to the other if that is appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already asked on another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having difficulty finding information on the "ARM data path" because there have been many different ARM microarchitectures with different data paths. There is not a single microarchitecture. (This is not even the case for MIPS; what you're familiar with is a simplified version!)

Smaller ARM processors, like Cortex-M microcontrollers, use [a simple three-stage pipeline](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/CACCIFED.html). This is *not* the same as the MIPS pipeline, but is roughly comparable. Larger ARM processors, like the Cortex-A series, use a variety of superscalar microarchitectures; for details, see the appropriate ARM Architecture Reference Manual. (This isn't freely available online, but [can be downloaded from ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) if you have an account.)

Answer (score 2):

> because the data path involves fetching, decoding, and executing the instruction and it must be same for all Instruction Set Architectures.

That's in fact a little true and a little false:

You can usually logically divide your processor into these steps, but that's a way of *looking* at it.

Especially for complex CPU cores, and even more so if pipelining and speculative operation is used, the lines between e.g. decoding and executing can get a bit blurry.

Even more: many (especially non-RISC) architectures actually operate with a different instruction internally set than what their "public" ISA is.

If the ISA has an indirect register address mode, and the decode stage converts that to a fixed-register instruction in the microcode, marking that register as in operation (so that things that get pushed into the pipeline know they must wait until the register modify is finish should they need to read it), is that already part of execution, or still decoding?

If you have an intelligent pipeline that sees a branch and fetches only the "more likely" next instruction, isn't that also already a "premature" execution?

So, you're mapping concepts to real implementations. That gives you the freedom to interpret stuff, but also a lack of clarity.

Then, ARM isn't one core – there's a relatively wide range of ARM cores, which might exhibit the same ISA (or rather, one of the four ARM ISAs), but they work quite differently internally, and their pipelines differ substantially – from the more space optimized cortex-M cores over the defined-latency cortex-R to the application processors with SIMD extensions and looong pipelines.